# Why does eclipse not like "driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile);"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium

am trying to follow along with a time sensitive selenium course and I am just getting hopelessly lost. I was only able to execute this test the first time using chrome and not firefox but then i started getting errors connecting to chrome and went back to firefox. Below is the script from the tutorial course which SHOULD work. I have added the path to firefox.exe in my system variables and I am running firefox 47 which I downgraded to see if that would help. I'm using JDK 1.8 and selenium 3.6.0. Here is the code from the course. My eclipse is borking at the line driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile); the red underline asks to "remove this argument to match firefoxDriver".

If I remove it according to the instructions as just have driver = new Firefox Driver, I then get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at Guru99package.TestScript02.main(TestScript02.java:72)

Line 72 is the starting line for the whole main function, so this is really unclear for me. As far as I can tell, the reason it won't compile could be anything and the syntax for firefox path matches what I'm seeing in github tutorials and google.

I tried doing this in chrome and can paste my results here, but I also got really confused in chrome as to whether I was supposed to instantiate my webdriver using webdriver or RemoteWebDriver. When I called Chrome like this:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

my script initially ran but wouldn't input anything in the login fields. Now it seems that nothing I do is working. The tutorial doesn't have a forum or help options.

Code for the main file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;




public class TestScript02 {

static WebDriver driver; // Selenium control driver
private static String baseUrl; // baseUrl of Website Guru99

// This method SetUp will read initialization parameters from the          classUtil.java & launch Firefox 

public static void setUp() throws Exception {
/*
 * Tells the Selenium client library to connect to the Webdriver
 * service using firefox
 * 
 * In some PC's, Selenium can not find the binary file of Firefox because
 * user doesn't install Firefox at its default location. We need to tell
 * Selenium where the firefox.exe is
 */
    File pathToBinary = new File(Util.FIREFOX_PATH);
    FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);

/*
 * Create new firefoxProfile for Testing
 * 
 * A profile in Firefox is a collection of bookmarks, browser settings,
 * extensions, passwords, and history; in short, all of your personal
 * settings. Firefox uses a DEFAULT profile to store all of your
 * personal settings.
 * 
 * In this case, we use Firefox for "testing" purpose not as an "end user".
 * We need to create NEW firefoxProfile because we want to separate the
 * Firefox profile for testing purpose and that of an end user. If
 * something wrong happens with the testing, you still have your DEFAULT
 * profile to fall back to (your personal data still safe).
 */
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile);

// Setting Base URL of website Guru99
baseUrl = Util.BASE_URL;
// Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present.
// Refer - http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html
driver.manage().timeouts()
    .implicitlyWait(Util.WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Go to http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/
driver.get(baseUrl + "/V4/");
}

/**
 * 
 * @author Krishna Rungta
 *        Test Script 02
 *        ************** 
 *        This method will perform following Test Steps
 *        
 *        1)  Go to http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/
          2) Enter valid UserId
          3) Enter valid Password
          4) Click Login
          5) Verify the Page Title after login
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



String username, password;
String actualTitle;
String actualBoxtitle;


    //Setup Firefox driver
    setUp();


    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).clear(); // Good practice to clear a field before use
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys(Util.USER_NAME);  // Enter username


    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear(); // Good practice to clear a field before use
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Util.PASSWD);  // Enter Password

    // Click Login
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();

    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    if (actualTitle.contains(Util.EXPECT_TITLE)) {
                System.out.println("Test case: Passed");
    } 
    else {
                System.out.println("Test case : Failed");
    }

    driver.close();



}

}
```

Code for util.java:

```
package Guru99package;

public class Util {

/* You can change the Path of FireFox based on your environment here */
public static final String FIREFOX_PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

// Setting Base URL
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.demo.guru99.com/";

// Time to wait when searching for a GUI element 
public static final int WAIT_TIME = 30; 


// Valid account for login
public static final String USER_NAME = "mngr103067";
public static final String PASSWD = "pepysYd";


// Expected output
public static final String EXPECT_TITLE = "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage";


}
```

Comment: I think it be a issue with your Selenium version. The code looks like from Selenium 2.X version and you are using Selenium3.X

Comment: Does Selenium 3.X use Remote Webdriver as opposed to Webdriver? Would you suggest deleting Selenium 3 and downloading Selenium 2 or do you know the structure to change this to run find in selenium 3?

Comment: Just try `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and it should work

Comment: with driver = new FirefoxDriver() I get this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at Guru99package.TestScript02.main(TestScript02.java:72)

Comment: Try to use minimal code which just initiates the driver first and then start increasing. That will make sure you understand which lines don't work anymore